# How to load a sharePoint page in "safe mode"?

Tags: error, debugging

I seem to remember that there was a way to add something to the query string for a SharePoint page that would basically load the page in a "safe mode".  In this mode you could delete or edit webparts.

Does anyone know what I am talking about here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Append `?contents=1` to the end of your query string to delete broken web parts from the page.