# SPD 2010: How to use advanced and normal mode of editing?

Tags: 2010, development, sharepoint-designer, html-editor

In SharePoint Designer 2010, when I create a new aspx page (Site --> Righ-click on blank in the right pane --> New --> ASPX) and then open it for editing, I am getting:

- "This page does not contain any regions that are editable in safe mode. Do you want to open this page in advanced mode?
   Yes/No"

And if I click "No", I am blocked from editing.
So, if I enter page management view and enter editor by clicking "Edit file", I am unable to enter editor in Advanced mode or blocked refusing normal one.

What are safe and unsafe editing and elements I am prevented to edit in SPD2 2010?
One can understand this warning, that advanced = unsafe?  i.e permit editing safe regions?

Though, from [How to load a sharePoint page in “safe mode”?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19069/how-to-load-a-sharepoint-page-in-safe-mode) follows the opposite definition of safe editing.

What are the differences between advanced and normal mode of editing?

Is "advanced mode" for safe or unsafe editing?
How can I detect in which mode I am editing and switch between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Safe" mode is pretty much limited to adding and modifying web parts inside web part zones.  So when you use this mode you're not making any changes to the actual structure of the page, just defining and configuring web parts. When you edit in Advanced mode, you are free to alter any part of the page structure.  In this case it is said you are "customizing" the page.

Why is this distinction important?  By default SharePoint's basic page layouts are stored in the server's file system and they are loaded from the file system when requested by a user.  This is one of the things that makes SharePoint so scalable at a massive level.  When you customize a page, you are breaking that pointer to the physical file and replacing it with a custom page living in the content database.  This will affect performance and will cause databases to become unwieldy if there are a large number of these pages.

So SharePoint gives you the performance of staying within the bounds of the OOB pages, and the flexibility to roll your own if you need to.

Comment: ...and the post you linked to was regarding the web parts maintenance page - an unrelated topic.

Comment: oh, and one more thing - when you create a new aspx in the manner you described there are no web part zones, so anything you do to it will make it a customized page. That's what it means by saying there are no regions editable in safe mode.

Comment: Derek, thanks. So, safe mode = Normal mode? Funny but this basic info is available in most tutorials. Plz comment the post of a user to whom you address, otherwise there are no notifications in system of addressee about your comments

Comment: Is this distinction present while editing through a browser (without external editing tools)?